# Staggered and stacked geom_bar in the same figure?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following graph, which is essentially two distributions' histograms plotted alongside each other:

```
my.barplot <- function( df, title="", ... ) {
  df.count <- aggregate( df$outcome, by=list(df$category1,df$outcome), FUN=length )
  colnames( df.count ) <- c("category1","outcome","n")
  df.total <- aggregate( df.count$n, by=list(df.count$category1), FUN=sum )
  colnames( df.total ) <- c("category1","total")
  df.dens <- merge(df.count, df.total)
  df.dens$dens <- with( df.dens, n/total )
  p <- ggplot( df.dens, aes( x=outcome, fill=category1 ), ... )
  p <- p + geom_bar( aes( y=dens ), position="dodge" )
  p <- p + opts( axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90,hjust=0), title=title )
  p
}

N <- 50*(2*8*2)
outcome <- sample(ordered(seq(8)),N,replace=TRUE,prob=c(seq(4)/20,rev(seq(4)/20)) )
category2 <- ifelse( outcome==1, sample(c("yes","not"), prob=c(.95,.05)), sample(c("yes","not"), prob=c(.35,.65)) )
dat <- data.frame(
  category1=rep(c("in","out"),each=N/2),
  category2=category2,
  outcome=outcome
  )

my.barplot(dat)
```

[image: existing barchart]

I'd like to plot within each bar the proportion belonging to some second category.  Absent the need to organize it by the first category, I would just stack the bars.  However, I can't figure out how to stack by a second category.  Basically within each outcome-category1 bar I want the proportion in category2 to be darker shaded.

Here's a GIMP'd image of what I'm trying to create:

[image: barchart with stacked proportions of category2]

Comment: I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ggplot2/combining$20dodge$20and$20stack/ggplot2/m8FcaqKggLo/I1LPnUvq3nUJ) rather old thread from the mailing list. Not sure if this functionality was ever rolled into a later version or not.

Comment: Sorry I don't have more time at the moment, but I thought I'd drop this link in hopes that it gives you ideas: http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/ggplot2-marimekko-replacement-overlapping-bars/  In summary: plot two separate layers of bars.  You could then either use different color schemes for the bars, or use the same color scheme and use `alpha()` to make them, say, half-transparent - unstacked is a lighter shade, stacked is the full color.

Comment: Thanks joran and Matt.  I'll give the layers and alpha trick a try, hopefully later today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base graphics?!? NEVERRRR

Here's what I've come up with.  I admit I had a hard time understanding all your aggregation and prep, so I just aggregated to counts and may have gotten that all wrong - but it seems like you're in a position where it might be easier to start from a functioning plot and then get the inputs right.  Does this do the trick?

```
# Aggregate
dat.agg <- ddply(dat, .var = c("category1", "outcome"), .fun = summarise,
                 cat1.n = length(outcome),
                 yes = sum(category2 %in% "yes"),
                 not = sum(category2 %in% "not")
)


# Plot - outcome will be x for both layers
ggplot(dat.agg, aes(x = outcome)) +

    # First layer of bars - for category1 totals by outcome
    geom_bar(aes(weight = cat1.n, fill = category1), position = "dodge") +

    # Second layer of bars - number of "yes" by outcome and category1
    geom_bar(aes(weight = yes, fill = category1), position = "dodge") +

    # Transparency to make total lighter than "yes" - I am bad at colors
    scale_fill_manual(value = c(alpha("#1F78B4", 0.5), alpha("#33A02C", 0.5))) +

    # Title
    opts(title = "A pretty plot <3")
```

[image: Plot with bars that are simultaneously dodged, overlaid, and transparent]

Comment: I <3 this!  That's perfect.  You stacked the dodges rather than trying to dodge the stacks, if that makes any sense at all :-)

Comment: Any hints on how to add a legend for category2, since category1 is the fill for both?  6.4.5 of the ggplot2 book sort of suggests that identity_scale might do it, but on further reading, it looks like it makes things not have a legend instead, so I'm clueless.

Comment: @gsk3 Yeah, that's a major flaw of this approach - there's just no way to get a legend because, as far as ggplot's concerned, there are only two colors here.  I think you'd have to restructure the data in a pretty fundamental way, and I just can't come up with it right now.  I noticed you're familiar with GIMP, however...

Comment: Actually, on reflection, that's exactly what I'd do.  Plot as above, copy/paste the category1 legend, and then use eyedropper + fill to set the colors from the bars themselves.  As long as you're not making a million of these plots, that's a pretty manageable kludge.

Answer (score 1):

I like @MattP's comment; I'd only add that an alternative to `alpha()` is to specify transparency directly.  For example,  #FF0000 is solid color and #FF000033 is pale/partially transparent color.
   As always,  searching through http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/  may help you find some code to create the exact style of graph you're after.

Comment: Interesting - how do you evaluate what level of transparency you're putting in?  Just playing around with that, it seems like "#1F78B499" is about equivalent to `alpha("#1F78B4", 0.5)` - how would you do, say, 75% opaque?

Comment: @Matt: the last two digits, like the two-digit color values themselves, run from 00 to FF.  You do the math :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I gave it a shot but haven't made a ton of progress beyond putting the appropriate densities in the same data.frame:

```
my.barplot <- function( df, title="", legend.title="",... ) {
  df.count12 <- aggregate( df$outcome, by=list(df$category1,df$category2,df$outcome), FUN=length )
  colnames( df.count12 ) <- c("category1","category2","outcome","n")
  df.total <- aggregate( df.count12$n, by=list(df.count12$category1), FUN=sum )
  colnames( df.total ) <- c("category1","total")
  # Densities within a bar - Categories 1 & 2
  df.dens12 <- merge(df.count12, df.total)
  df.dens12$dens12 <- with( df.dens12, n/total )
  # Total bar height - Category 1 density
  df.count1 <- aggregate( df.dens12$n, by=list(df.dens12$category1,df.dens12$outcome), FUN=sum )
  colnames( df.count1 ) <- c("category1","outcome","n")
  df.dens1 <- merge(df.count1,df.total)
  df.dens1$dens1 <- with(df.dens1, n/total)
  # Merge both into the final dataset
  df.dens <- merge(df.dens12,df.dens1,all.x=TRUE,by=c("category1","outcome"))
  df.dens <- subset(df.dens, select=c(-total.x) )
  colnames( df.dens ) <- sub("\\.x","12",colnames(df.dens))
  colnames( df.dens ) <- sub("\\.y","1",colnames(df.dens))
  # Plot 
  ymax <- max(df.dens$dens1)
  # Plot 1: category1
  p <- ggplot( df.dens, aes( x=outcome, fill=category1 ), ... )
  p1 <- p + geom_bar( aes( y=dens1 ), position="dodge" )
  p1 <- p1 + opts( axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90,hjust=0), title=title )
  if(legend.title!="") { p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_discrete(name=legend.title) }
  # Plot 2: category2
  p2 <- p1 + geom_bar( aes( y=dens12, fill=category2 ), position="stack", stat="identity" )
  p2
}

N <- 50*(2*8*2)
outcome <- sample(ordered(seq(8)),N,replace=TRUE,prob=c(seq(4)/20,rev(seq(4)/20)) )
category2 <- ifelse( outcome==1, sample(c("yes","not"), prob=c(.95,.05)), sample(c("yes","not"), prob=c(.35,.65)) )
dat <- data.frame(
  category1=rep(c("in","out"),each=N/2),
  category2=category2,
  outcome=outcome
  )

my.barplot(dat, title="Test title", legend.title="Medical system")
```

Comparing my attempts with the link, it's clear that he's putting the third dimension (x=outcome, dodge=category1, stack=category2) alongside using the grid layout, whereas I really need the third dimension stacked inside the second dimension.  I think I may have reached the point where ggplot2 is being tortured too much and I should just write out a function using base graphics.  Woe.