# In ggplot2, how do you combine small valued bars in a stacked histogram together?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Example data:

```
tmp_df <-  
    data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                      b = rnorm(100, 0.5, 1),
                      c = rnorm(100, -0.5, 1),
                      d = rnorm(100, 1, 1),
                      e = rnorm(100, -1, 1)) %>%
    tidyr::gather()
```

and producing a stacked histogram:

```
tmp_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = key)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, position = 'stack')
```

[image]

All well and good, in each bin, we have 5 different coloured bars showing the counts in each bin for each group.

What do I do if I only want to show the counts for the top N (say N = 2) groups for each bin, and classify and aggregate the other counts into an 'other' group?

For example, for N = 2 and the bin centred on zero, I would like to show the count  of `a` and `c` falling into this bins as separate bars, but combine the bar lengths of `b`, `d`, and `e` into one. For the bin centred on approx -1.4, I want to show the counts for group `e` and `c`, but aggregate the other two.

Comment: Might be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287532/ggplot-stacked-bar-chart-with-alpha-differences-within-each-stacked-category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a post-hoc approach. ggplot creates its own data frame for drawing a figure. The data frame has all details, and you can wisely use them.

```
# Let's create a data set with set.seed().
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(111)
tmp_df <-  data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                      b = rnorm(100, 0.5, 1),
                      c = rnorm(100, -0.5, 1),
                      d = rnorm(100, 1, 1),
                      e = rnorm(100, -1, 1)) %>%
tidyr::gather()

# Save the original data
tmp_df %>%
ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = key)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, position = 'stack') -> g
```

Now you create a new data frame using `g`. You can see how this data frame looks like below.

```
# Create a data frame
ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]] %>%
data.frame -> temp

#     fill y count    x  xmin  xmax density ncount ndensity PANEL group ymin ymax colour size linetype
#1 #E76BF3 1     1 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.1  0.125     1.25     1     5    0    1     NA  0.5        1
#2 #00B0F6 1     0 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     4    1    1     NA  0.5        1
#3 #00BF7D 1     0 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     3    1    1     NA  0.5        1
#4 #A3A500 1     0 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     2    1    1     NA  0.5        1
#5 #F8766D 1     0 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     1    1    1     NA  0.5        1
#6 #E76BF3 0     0 -4.1 -4.15 -4.05     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     5    0    0     NA  0.5        1
```

I wanted to check how colors were assigned to each group. So I took a part of data which has 0 for x-axis. This information will be used later.

```
# Check how colors are assigned to each group

filter(temp, x == 0) %>%
select(fill) %>%
unlist %>%
rev

#     fill5     fill4     fill3     fill2     fill1 
# "#F8766D" "#A3A500" "#00BF7D" "#00B0F6" "#E76BF3"
```

Then, I wanted to manipulate the data frame a bit. In order to find the top 2 groups for each group (for each bin), I subtracted `ymin` from `ymax` and created a new column called `y2`. The values in this column tells which groups stay in the top two positions. So, for each group (each x value), I arranged the data in descending order with `y2`. Then, I replaced the values in `y2` for the groups staying in the 3rd-5th position. If there were ties, in each group, the first one was chosen here.

```
temp %>%
mutate(y2 = ymax - ymin) %>%
arrange(x, desc(y2)) %>%
group_by(x) %>%
mutate(group = as.character(c(group[1:2], rep(6, times = 3)))) %>%
ungroup -> temp2
```

The final step was to draw a figure again. As eipi10 used geom_bar, I used the same function.

```
ggplot(data = temp2, aes(x = x, y = y2, fill = group)) +
geom_bar(width = 0.1, stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(name = "key", labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "others"),
           values = c("#F8766D", "#A3A500", "#00BF7D", "#00B0F6", "#E76BF3", "#000000")) +
labs(x = "value", y = "count") -> g2
```

[image]

For the comparison graphic below

```
arrangeGrobe(g, g2, ncol = 2) -> g3
ggsave(g3, file = "whatever.png", width = 12, height = 9)
```

Comparison with the original figure (left)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent answer as it taught me about the hidden data frame in a ggplot object, and how to manipulate raw data in this data frame to modify the underlying ggplot. For simplicity, @eipi10's answer should be preferred.

Comment: @Alex Pleasure to help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a new grouping variable (which we'll call `group`) that, for each bin, takes the value of `key` for the top two levels of `key` or `other` for other three levels of `key`. To make this work, you bin and tally the data before plotting it, and then create the new `group` column and use it as the `fill` aesthetic in `ggplot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Set a seed for reproducibility
set.seed(59)
tmp_df <-  
  data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
             b = rnorm(100, 0.5, 1),
             c = rnorm(100, -0.5, 1),
             d = rnorm(100, 1, 1),
             e = rnorm(100, -1, 1)) %>%
  tidyr::gather()
```

In the code below, we bin the data and create the new grouping variable. I used bins 0.2 units wide with labels equal to the mid-points of the bins. To create the `group` column, we use `rank` to find the two most common values of `key` in each bin and set the rest to "other".

```
tmp_df = tmp_df %>% 
  group_by(key, 
           bins=cut(value, seq(-10,10,0.2), labels=seq(-9.9,9.9,0.2))) %>%
  tally %>%
  group_by(bins) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(key %in% key[rank(-n, ties="first") %in% 1:2], key, "other")) %>%
  arrange(bins, key)
```

Now, for the plot we use `geom_bar` and we fill with the new `group` column we created above. Also, we convert `bins` (the bin labels) from factor to numeric, so that the x-axis will be continuous, rather than discrete.

```
tmp_df %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(bins = as.numeric(as.character(bins))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=bins, y=n, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=6)[1:5],100,65),"black"))
```

Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is very straightfoward and easy to understand/implement.