# How does the group column from ggplot_build correspond to the original factor levels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a follow-up question based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274625/in-ggplot2-how-do-you-combine-small-valued-bars-in-a-stacked-histogram-together/41275912?noredirect=1#comment70075568_41275912), where in the `scale_fill_manual` bit in the following line of code:

```
ggplot(data = temp2, aes(x = x, y = y2, fill = group)) +
geom_bar(width = 0.1, stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(name = "key", labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "others"),
           values = c("#F8766D", "#A3A500", "#00BF7D", "#00B0F6", "#E76BF3", "#000000")) +
labs(x = "value", y = "count") -> g2
```

the colour values and legend labels were determined using some mapping to the `group` column in the data frame generated by `ggplot_build`. My question regards the determination of this mapping, especially when the `group` column is derived from a factor column with incomplete factor levels.

For example:

```
set.seed(111)
tmp_df <-  
    data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
               b = rnorm(100, 0.5, 1),
               c = rnorm(100, -0.5, 1),
               d = rnorm(100, 1, 1),
               e = rnorm(100, -1, 1)) %>%
    tidyr::gather() %>%
    mutate(key = factor(key, levels = letters[1:5]))
```

Now create stacked bar chart and generate underlying raw data:

```
tmp_df %>%
    filter(key != "c") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = key)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, position = 'stack') ->
    p

tmp_raw_df <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
```

Inspecting `tmp_raw_df`:

```
> head(tmp_raw_df)
     fill y count    x  xmin  xmax density ncount ndensity PANEL group ymin ymax colour size linetype alpha
1 #C77CFF 1     1 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.1  0.125     1.25     1     4    0    1     NA  0.5        1    NA
2 #00BFC4 1     0 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     3    1    1     NA  0.5        1    NA
3 #7CAE00 1     0 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     2    1    1     NA  0.5        1    NA
4 #F8766D 1     0 -4.2 -4.25 -4.15     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     1    1    1     NA  0.5        1    NA
5 #C77CFF 0     0 -4.1 -4.15 -4.05     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     4    0    0     NA  0.5        1    NA
6 #00BFC4 0     0 -4.1 -4.15 -4.05     0.0  0.000     0.00     1     3    0    0     NA  0.5        1    NA
```

We see that the values of `key` have been mapped to group numbers 1-4. My question is, how is this mapping done, and how do I recover the original values of key, or factor levels, from the `group` column in `tmp_raw_df`?

Comment: I cannot say how the mapping is done (although I suspect by refactoring `key`, dropping unused levels, and converting to integers), but I'm confident that `ggplot_build(p)$data` does not contain the original values of `key` any more. These values should now live in one of the scales of the plot.

Comment: thanks, so how/where should one go to retrieve these values?

Comment: In all likelihood, one should go in one of the `ggproto` objects of the plot, but given how these are evaluated, I am unsure that you will be able to (easily) retrieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Usually factors are assigned alphabetically after they are refactored like @Fr. said. So if you wanted to check, you could manually create a histogram or a binning with the same bins as in `ggplot` and compare them to the non-zero bins in `tmp_raw_df`.  You may already know this, but for a `factor` object, you can retrieve the values with `levels()` and then match them up.  However, the data is essentially lost after it disappears into `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aye, even if you try to use `drop=FALSE` to preserve factor integrity the current rev of ggplot will keep that for the legend display but still end up dropping them for the final data build for the `grid` drawing. You can use the manual fill values to provide reverse mapping:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(111)

data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
           b = rnorm(100, 0.5, 1),
           c = rnorm(100, -0.5, 1),
           d = rnorm(100, 1, 1),
           e = rnorm(100, -1, 1)) %>%
  tidyr::gather() %>%
  mutate(key = factor(key, levels = letters[1:5])) -> tmp_df

factor_map <- c(a="#111111", b="#222222", c="#333333", d="#444444", e="#555555")
rev_map <- setNames(names(factor_map), unname(factor_map))

tmp_df %>%
  filter(key != "c") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = key)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, position = 'stack') +
  scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE, values=factor_map) -> p

tmp_raw_df <- tbl_df(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]])

tmp_raw_df <- mutate(tmp_raw_df, orig_factor=rev_map[fill])

distinct(tmp_raw_df, fill, group, orig_factor)
## # A tibble: 4 × 3
##      fill group orig_factor
##     <chr> <int>       <chr>
## 1 #555555     4           e
## 2 #444444     3           d
## 3 #222222     2           b
## 4 #111111     1           a
```