# Split R bar graph with total frequency and levels

Tags: r

i want to plot a bar graph in R showing the total frequency side by side with the different levels color coded in individual bars.

For example if we have the following data table or data frame in R
Df<-
   Y.      Total.       a.       b.     c
   Jan.   15.          6.      5.      4
 April.  17.         7.      5.      5
 Sep.    20.         9.      7.      4
 Dec.   25.          11.   8.      6

Then i want to plot a bar graph with x axis= Y
Y axis = Total -intervel of frequency 5 
And a,b,c color coded in each bar along with Y

Split each bar along the x axis with half part showing different a,b,c levels for each Y and half part showing the Total for Y ( in color code).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a stacked bar chart? If so, you need to `reshape2::melt()` your data while excluding `Total`, and then use `ggplot2` to plot:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Y = c("Jan", "April", "Sep", "Dec"),
                 Total = c(15,17,20,25),
                 a = c(6,7,9,11),
                 b = c(5,5,7,8),
                 c = c(4,5,4,6))
df1 <- melt(df[,-2], id.vars = "Y")

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Y, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

Comment: This i can do, i want each bar split into half with this(a,b,c) and total frequency(Total) side by side

Comment: What i want is to show a,b,c and Total side by side in each bar

Comment: @AbhinavSharma It's not at all clear what you're after. The total is just the sum of `a,b,c` which corresponds to the max height. That's the whole point of a stacked bar chart. Can you edit your original post to include a mock-up of your expected output plot?

Comment: Yes very correct but it is a requirement to show that total color coded for each Y in the same bar along with the levels side on

Comment: @AbhinavSharma You might find something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493159/staggered-and-stacked-geom-bar-in-the-same-figure